# tr1::array in C++ deleting all elements

Tags: c++, stl

how to delete all elements of a std::tr1::array?

For example I have defined the following array.

`std::tr1::array <int, 5> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Just like in vectors  I am looking for a method such as `a.clear()` or `a.erase()` but couldn't find one for arrays.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arrays are static size, you can neither add nor remove elements, that's what vector is for.

Comment: Thanks. what I really wanted was to 'clear' the information within the array, keeping the size same. Now I understand why clear / erase won't work. All I need is `a.assign(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Once defined, the size of an array cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a fixed size.  You can, however, keep track of the number of elements you use in the array, for a fixed-maximum-sized-vector:

```
array<int,5> arr;
int number_of_elements = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
    // arr.push_back(i)
    arr[number_of_elements] = i;
    number_of_elements++;
}

// arr.erase( arr.begin() + 2 )
for ( int i = 2; i < number_of_elements-1; ++i )
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
number_of_elements--;

// arr.clear()
number_of_elements = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can delete specific index information if want!

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)                                     //for deletion
        {
            if(arr[i]==_delete)
            {   
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
               --n;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question is 8 years old and was already answered. Also your answer doesn't add any value, which is already provided by @fastcall22